# Page jumps when useState updates

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to build a clone of a [MovieDataBase site](https://www.themoviedb.org/?language=en-US) in react, and when I update my state variable the page jumps ( it jumps up exactly 60px, for whatever reason, and then back down again each time I toggle the switch).  I thought it was maybe because I'm interacting with the DOM to get the toggle switch to work, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.  I've also been told that happens with styled components, which I don't think I have (still pretty new to REACT, so maybe???).  Anyway - I can't figure out why this is happening.  I've included the code for the component in question below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import API_KEY from "../../config";

const Popular = ({ imageUri }) => {
  // GET POPULAR MOVIES
  const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = useState("");
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState("movie");
  const getPopular = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/${genre}?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=${API_KEY}`
    );
    setPopularMovies(response.data.results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPopular();
  }, [genre]);

  const listOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".switch--option");
  const background = document.querySelector(".background");

  const changeHandler = (el) => {
    let getGenre = el.target.dataset.genre;
    setGenre(getGenre);
    listOptions.forEach((option) => {
      option.classList.remove("selected");
    });

    el = el.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    let getStartingLeft = Math.floor(
      listOptions[0].getBoundingClientRect().left
    );
    let getLeft = Math.floor(el.getBoundingClientRect().left);
    let getWidth = Math.floor(el.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    let leftPos = getLeft - getStartingLeft;
    background.setAttribute(
      "style",
      `left: ${leftPos}px; width: ${getWidth + 1}px`
    );
    el.classList.add("selected");

  };

  const isMovieSelected = genre === "movie";
  const isTvSelected = genre === "tv";
  const movieData = "movie";
  const tvData = "tv";



  return (
    <section className="container movie-list">
      <div className="flex flex--align-center">
        <MovieHeader>What's Popular</MovieHeader>
        <div className="switch flex">
          <Toggle
            onChange={changeHandler}
            selected={isMovieSelected}
            data={movieData}
          >
            In Theaters
            <div className="background"></div>
          </Toggle>
          <Toggle
            onChange={changeHandler}
            selected={isTvSelected}
            data={tvData}
          >
            On TV
          </Toggle>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="scroller">
        <div className="flex flex--justify-center">
          <div className="flex flex--nowrap container u-overScroll">
            {popularMovies &&
              popularMovies.map((movie) => {
                const { title, id, poster_path } = movie;
                return (
                  <MovieItem
                    title={title}
                    imageUri={imageUri}
                    key={id}
                    poster_path={poster_path}
                  />
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Popular;

const Toggle = (props) => {
  const { children, onChange, selected, data } = props;
  const className = selected ? "switch--option selected" : "switch--option";
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <h3>
        <a data-genre={data} onClick={onChange} className="switch--anchor">
          {children}
        </a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
};

const MovieHeader = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  return (
    <div className="movie-list__header">
      <h3>{children}</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

const MovieItem = (props) => {
  const { title, imageUri, poster_path, id } = props;
  return (
    <div key={id} className="card">
      <div className="image">
        <img src={imageUri + "w500" + poster_path} />
      </div>
      <p>{title}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Looks like its not problem with react. it will be the style you are setting. you are changing some style inside 'changeHandler' and setting some state which cause the component to rerender. This will reset the style you set previously in 'changeHandler' as you are setting style directly to the DOM. In react setting style directly is not preferred. instead use a state and then use that state so that it will be in place after rerender.

Comment: I thought that too.   But when I take out all of the lines that change the styles, the problem still persist.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox or something to playaround?

Comment: Can I do that with an app that has several files and folders?   Would a git repo work?

Comment: Yes It will be fine.